# Error while importing ES Module in commonjs via Dynamic import

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules, commonjs, dynamic-import

We have an inhouse developed module that we need to use in a commonjs project.
In case in main.page.ts we import login.page than an **"Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:_AutomationProjects\CTA\Playwright\dist\page-objects\esm2020\lib\login.page' imported from C:_AutomationProjects\CTA\Playwright\dist\page-objects\esm2020\lib\main.page.mjs"** appears. It appears that dynamic import is not working in this case..otherwise no problem

Contents of the inhouse developed module:

**login.page.ts**

```
export class LoginPage {
  public page: Page;
  constructor(page: Page) {
    this.page = page;
  }
}
```

**main.page.ts**

```
import { LoginPage } from "./login.page";

export class MainPage {
  public page: Page;
  public login: LoginPage;
  constructor(page: Page) {
    this.page = page;
    this.login = new LoginPage(page);
  }
}
```

Then this project is installed in another one that is commonjs and to use it we make use on dynamic imports

**main.cjs**

```
mainPage = new (await import('../../dist/page-objects/esm2020/lib/main.page.mjs')).MainPage(page);
```

If in main.page.ts we remove the login.page import that everything is working.

How can we import es modules in commonjs in this case?

Comment: Why do you have to use commonjs with your other project?

Comment: I am restricted to commonjs due to a test tool that only supports commonjs